# MVC5 When I create a controller and I make a list view the error show Unable to retrieve metadata

Tags: asp.net

this are my codes I am new in mvc 5

[image]

Comment: can i look into your web config's connection string..??

Comment: Ok sir I will send

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Multitable_database_application-20160420021655.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Multitable_database_application-20160420021655;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Answer (score 0):

If your connection string in web.config have

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
```

change it into:

```
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

maybe this help you :)

Comment: ironically today i faced this issue, I have solved this issue by changing provider name here is my connection string , maybe this will help you `<add name="dalKey" connectionString="Data Source=W3S-PC5;Initial Catalog=key;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`